# Javascript: passing the 'this' value

Tags: javascript, oop, event-listener

I have the following code:

```
function Selector()
{
 ...
 this.items = new Array();
 // i load here the items with dom-s
 this.setActiveItem = function(item)
 {
  this.items[item].className = "selector-item-active";
  ...
 }
 var _this = this;
 for (var i=0; i<itemsName.length; i++)
  this.items[i].addEventListener("mouseup",function(){_this.setActiveItem(i)});
}
```

The problem is that when the listener calls the **setActiveItem** function then i get the following message in console:

*Cannot set property 'className' of undefined*

So the listener cannot pass the **this** value.

Is there any solution?

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like your defining a property of an array item, without defining what the array item is to begin with.

Comment: I think your actual elements are inside that array, so you should pass `this.items[i]` into the listener, rather than `this`. So put the `_this` inside the for, like this: `var _this = this.items[i];`, that may solve your issue (depending on what exactly your array is).

Comment: see this article - [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FClosures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake). The reason why you're getting that error is because the value of `i` is `itemsName.length` which is beyond the bounds of the array, and trying to access `this.items[item]` returns `undefined`, followed by the error message you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value of i would be equal to  `itemsName.length` at whenever mouseup event execute. use anonymous function to preserve i;

Modified code:

```
.......
 var _this = this;
 for (var i=0; i<itemsName.length; i++){
  (function(j){
           _this.items[j].addEventListener("mouseup",
                        function(){
                              _this.setActiveItem(j);
                        }
                 );
            })(i);// preserve i for each for loop iterations
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Event listeners do not retain the the `this` scope of the object to which they belong. You also need to encapsulate the item index into the callback using a closure. Instead try referencing the variable using `_this` (as you've defined it), like this:

```
this.setActiveItem = function(item)
{
    return function (evt) {
        _this.items[item] = _this.items[item] || {};
        _this.items[item].className = "selector-item-active";
        ...
    }
}

...

for (var i=0; i<itemsName.length; i++)
    this.items[i].addEventListener("mouseup", this.setActiveItem(i));
```

Comment: I think, that this solution is the same like Sushil's answer. In this case you return with the inner function in the setActiveItem function.